# Mapeamento complexo Entity Framework

Tags: .net, banco-de-dados, orientação-a-objetos, entity-framework

Estou criando uma estrutura de classes que segue a seguinte forma:

Departamento
-Serviço

Um departamento presta vários tipos de de serviço. Um serviço em específico só pode ser prestado por um departamento, não por muitos.

Um departamento pode solicitar serviços a outros, e isso é previamente mapeado: Departamento **A** pode requisitar o serviço **B** (B  que por dua vez pertence ao departamento C).

Meu problema começa ai, pois preciso dizer que um **Departamento** pode requisitar um ou mais serviços de outros. Tentei algumas formas, incluindo colocar dois atributos do tipo "**Serviço**" na classe **Departamento** (duas coleções), mas quando o Entity gera o banco a estrutura de tabelas fica uma zona, com a tabela de **Serviços** com dois campos fazendo relação com **Departamento**.

Pensando de forma relacional, eu teria uma terceira tabela com id de Departamento e Serviço formando uma chave composta.

Como eu poderia mapear para classes (sem gerar uma zona no banco)?

Obrigado!

Comment: está utilizando `Fluent API`?

Comment: Estou sim, fluent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O departamento prestar um serviço é uma coisa. Um departamento tomar um serviço é outra. Você está tratando duas coisas diferentes como a mesma coisa. Pela sua explicação, o que temos é:

```
public class Departamento 
{
    [Key]
    public int DepartamentoId { get; set; }

    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Servico> Servicos { get; set; }
}

public class Servico 
{
    [Key]
    public int ServicoId { get; set; }
    public int DepartamentoId { get; set; }

    ...
    public virtual Departamento Departamento { get; set; }
}
```

Se um departamento está requisitando um serviço de outro, creio que deva existir um *Model* em separado pra isso. Por exemplo:

```
public class RequisicaoServico
{
    [Key]
    public int RequisicaoServicoId { get; set; }
    [Index("IUQ_RequisicaoServico_ServicoId_DepartamentoId", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
    public int ServicoId { get; set; }
    [Index("IUQ_RequisicaoServico_ServicoId_DepartamentoId", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
    public int DepartamentoId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DataRequisicao { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Boolean Finalizado { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Required]
    public String Descricao { get; set; }

    public virtual Departamento Departamento { get; set; }
    public virtual Servico Servico { get; set; }
}
```

[`[Index]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.indexattribute(v=vs.113).aspx), introduzido nesta forma a partir do Entity Framework 6.1.0, garante a unicidade do registro associativo. Validações adicionais podem ser necessárias na aplicação para evitar erros estranhos de duplicidade de chave para o usuário.

Sendo a tabela associativa, a única coisa que você precisaria fazer agora é atualizar os *Models* de `Departamento` e `Servico` para admitirem estar relacionados com uma `RequisicaoServico`, ou seja:

```
public class Departamento 
{
    [Key]
    public int DepartamentoId { get; set; }

    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Servico> Servicos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RequisicaoServico> RequisicoesServicos { get; set; }
}

public class Servico 
{
    [Key]
    public int ServicoId { get; set; }
    public int DepartamentoId { get; set; }

    ...
    public virtual Departamento Departamento { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RequisicaoServico> RequisicoesServicos { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Então, quase isso. Não estou de fato abrindo um serviço. Estou apenas mapeando qual departamento pode abrir quais serviços de outros departamentos. O Departamento Marketing pode solicitar o serviço Verificação de Contrato (que por sua vez é domínio do departamento Jurídico). Entendeu?

Comment: @StefanoSandes Então, basta alterar a associação para refletir essa realidade. Com algumas verificações de unicidade no *Controller*, está garantida uma lógica que não deixe inserir a mesma associação duas vezes no banco de dados.

Comment: Certo. Acho que meu problema é de mapeamento. As tabelas Departamento e Serviço são o feijão com arroz. Departamento tem nome e uma lista de serviços e Serviço tem um Departamento e um nome. Até aqui tudo funciona bem. Quando crio a classe DepartamentoServiço ela tem um Departamento e varios Serviços. Um departamento está habilitado a solicitar uma lista de serviços. Quando gero o banco o entity coloca Id do DepartamentoServiço na tabela Serviço, e pra mim isso não faz sentido. É como colocar o Id da pessoa no carro, só porque um carro pode carregar pessoas.

Comment: Então seu mapeamento está errado. Acho que seria o caso de abrir outra pergunta com o código dos *Models*.

Comment: Tem razão amigo, vou fazer isso. Muito obrigado!