# Mapeamento de tabela associativa com Entity Framework

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, entity-framework, code-first

Abstraindo alguns detalhes tenho estas classes:

```
public class Department: Entitie
{
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Service> Services {get; set;}
}

public class Service: Entitie
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Guid DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class DepartmentServiceRequest: Entitie
{
    public Guid DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Service> Services { get; set; }
}
```

A classe `DepartmentServiceRequest` é apenas uma das minha muitas tentativas de fazer isso funcionar.

Um **Departamento** presta vários **Serviços**. Um departamento pode solicitar um ou mais serviços a outro departamento, e isso precisa ser previamente mapeado. Ou seja, ele tem os serviços que presta e os que pode requisitar. O objetivo não é **registrar** um Serviço, é **mapear** quais tipos ele pode registrar.

No banco o resultado é esse:

[image: Resultado no banco]

Não entendo o motivo de ele estar levando o **Id** do **`DepartmentServiceRequest`** para o **Service**.

É possível via mapeamento informar que ele deve gerar essa tabela associativa apenas com os Ids de **`Department`** e **`Service`**? Isso me parece o mais lógico, pensando de forma relacional.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71261/mapeamento-complexo-entity-framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como eu falei, a associação está incorreta. Falta algumas informações na tabela associativa:

```
public class DepartmentServiceRequest: Entitie
{
    [Key]
    public Guid DepartmentServiceRequestId { get; set }
    [Index("IUQ_DepartmentServiceRequest_DepartmentId_ServiceId", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
    public Guid DepartmentId { get; set; }
    [Index("IUQ_DepartmentServiceRequest_DepartmentId_ServiceId", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
    public Guid ServiceId { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }    
    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
}
```

O motivo de ele estar levando a chave para `Service` é que você mesmo indicou isso nesta declaração:

```
public virtual ICollection<Service> Services { get; set; }
```

Isto está **incorreto** num escopo associativo. Com essa anotação, você está afirmando que uma `Request` tem vários serviços. Portanto, que cada `Service` está ligado a uma, e apenas uma `Request`, o que está errado.

O Entity Framework tenta, automaticamente, corrigir isso pra você, e inserir a chave extra é um comportamento correto. O que não está correto é a modelagem. [Na outra resposta que dei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71265/2999) eu já havia afirmado isso. Apenas estou digitando com outras palavras.

Não custa repetir: para que o comportamento fique completo, altere também `Department` e `Service` para aceitar o elo associativo:

```
public class Department: Entitie
{
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; private set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Service> Services {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<DepartmentServiceRequest> DepartmentServiceRequests {get; set;}
}

public class Service: Entitie
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Guid DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DepartmentServiceRequest> DepartmentServiceRequests {get; set;}
}
```

[`[Index]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.indexattribute(v=vs.113).aspx), introduzido nesta forma a partir do Entity Framework 6.1.0, garante a unicidade do registro associativo. Validações adicionais podem ser necessárias na aplicação para evitar erros estranhos de duplicidade de chave para o usuário.

Comment: Funcionou meu amigo! Eu realmente estranho um pouco o fato de a Service ter que fazer referência a DepartmentServiceRequest. Muito obrigado!